# Pasar a un archivo .csv un array numpy

Tags: python, numpy

estoy tratando de hacer un problema el cual necesito contar el numero de veces que se repiten unas temperaturas.

Adjunto el código.

```
# TODAS LAS FRECUENCIAS

'''
El archivo datos005.csv contienen, en enteros, las
temperaturas que ha habido en el interior de un aparato
que procesa alimentos. Las temperaturas oscilan entre
los -20 y los 60 grados, inclusive.

Realiza un programa que genera un archivo salida.csv
con la frecuencia (número de veces) en que se dio cada
temperatura.
'''

import numpy as np

array = np.loadtxt("datos005.csv", dtype = int)
array = np.sort(array)
array_aux = array
contador_temp = 0
condicion = True
aux_j = 0
j = 0

frecuencia_temp = np.zeros([81])
# sabemos que va a ocupar un array de 80 porque las temperaturas oscilan
# entre los -20 y 60 y las consideramos enteras (es decir, de 1 en 1)

for i in range(array.shape[0]):
    j = aux_j + 1
    
    while((j < array_aux.shape[0])):
        if(array[i] == array[j]):
            contador_temp += 1
            np.delete(array_aux,array_aux[j])
        else:
            j += 1

    frecuencia_temp[i] = contador_temp
    array = array_aux
    contador_temp = 0
    aux_j += 1

    
    

np.savetxt("Salida todas las frecuencias.csv", frecuencia_temp, fmt="%d")

print("Programa terminado con exito")
```

Sin embargo, no consigo que se eliminen las temperaturas una vez que se hayan contado, para que así no se vuelvan a contar repetidas veces. Deberían de salir 80 líneas (1 por cada temperatura) pero aparecen 1000 y no se que le falta al código para que funcione correctamente.

[Aquí esta el enlace de donde se sacan los datos](https://cutt.ly/mMM3gx6)

Un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sabiendo 0 de Python te comparto mi solucion, aunque deberias hacer caso a la respuesta de @abulafia. En todo caso funciona y crea un fichero **solo con las veces que se repiten las temperaturas** y coincide con la cantidad posible (80).

Comente todo para que entiendas que estoy haciendo:

```
import numpy as np
import csv

array = np.loadtxt("datos005.csv", dtype = int)
array = np.sort(array)
reslist = [] # lista resultado
counter = 0 # contador (solo es necesario uno)
current = array[0] # variable que contiene la temperatura actual evaluada, por defecto es el primer elemento

target = open('output.csv', 'w') # abrimos fichero objetivo
writer = csv.writer(target) # creamos un writer para escribir los resultados

#creando lista de resultados
for row in array: # para cada temperatura
    if row == current: # si es igual a la actual
        counter += 1 # incrementamos
    else: # sino
        current = row # ahora la temperatura actual es row (la siguiente temperatura no repetida)
        reslist.append(counter) # agregamos el contador a la lista resultado
        counter = 1 # reiniciamos

# escribiendo resultados en el fichero
for row in reslist:
    writer.writerow([row])
    
target.close() # cerramos lector de fichero
```

Comment: Esto es justo lo que estaba buscando, ya que me piden hacerlo de forma algorítmica y solo usando cosas métodos básicos.

Comment: @Toad de hecho el segundo for es innecesario, podes escribir directamente en el else

Answer (score 1):

No necesitas escribir todo ese código. Numpy es una librería que contiene montones de funciones de utilidad precisamente para que no tengas que hacer bucles iterando por los valores de un array (que es una operación lenta) sino que dejes que numpy haga las cuentas por tí (que es mucho más rápido porque las funciones internas de numpy están escritas en C).

En este caso basta una línea:

```
valores, contadores = np.unique(array, return_counts=True)
```

Esto te retorna dos arrays, el de valores contiene las temperaturas diferentes que se han observado en los datos, ordenadas de menor a mayor. El de contadores cuántas veces se ha repetido cada una de esas temperaturas.

Ahora puedes por ejemplo imprimir el resultado:

```
for valor, cuantos in zip(valores, contadores):
   print(valor, cuantos)
```

O crear un diccionario cuyas claves sean las temperaturas y los valores sean el contador de repeticiones:

```
diccionario = {valor: cuantos for valor, cuantos in zip(valores, contadores) }
```

El resultado sería este:

```
{-20: 18, -19: 7,  -18: 20, -17: 14, -16: 15, -15: 13, -14: 15, -13: 12,
 -12: 4,  -11: 19, -10: 18,  -9: 7,   -8: 15,  -7: 12,  -6: 15,  -5: 8, 
 -4:  5,   -3: 10,  -2: 9,   -1: 15,   0: 16,   1: 14,   2: 10,   3: 16, 
  4: 14,    5: 8,    6: 11,   7: 14,   8: 11,   9: 16,  10: 12,  11: 14,
 12: 17,   13: 15,  14: 16,  15: 16,  16: 18,  17: 15,  18: 6,   19: 6, 
 20: 11,   21: 7,   22: 14,  23: 14,  24: 14,  25: 10,  26: 15,  27: 13, 
 28: 22,   29: 20,  30: 14,  31: 6,   32: 9,   33: 9,   34: 11,  35: 10,
 36: 17,   37: 12,  38: 13,  39: 6,   40: 6,   41: 15,  42: 10,  43: 10,
 44: 6,    45: 11,  46: 12,  47: 9,   48: 10,  49: 12,  50: 9,   51: 8, 
 52: 14,   53: 16,  54: 10,  55: 16,  56: 11,  57: 15,  58: 12,  59: 13, 60: 12}
```

O puedes guardarlo en una estructura como la que usabas en tu ejemplo, aunque no le veo mucho sentido porque ¿cómo sabes a qué valor de temperatura corresponde cada contador? En todo caso, sería así:

```
frecuencia_temp = np.zeros([81])
frecuencia_temp[valores-min(valores)] = contadores
```

En este caso el resultado es:

```
[18.  7. 20. 14. 15. 13. 15. 12.  4. 19. 18.  7. 15. 12. 15.  8.  5. 10.
  9. 15. 16. 14. 10. 16. 14.  8. 11. 14. 11. 16. 12. 14. 17. 15. 16. 16.
 18. 15.  6.  6. 11.  7. 14. 14. 14. 10. 15. 13. 22. 20. 14.  6.  9.  9.
 11. 10. 17. 12. 13.  6.  6. 15. 10. 10.  6. 11. 12.  9. 10. 12.  9.  8.
 14. 16. 10. 16. 11. 15. 12. 13. 12.]
```

pero como dije, aquí se pierde la información de a qué temperatura corresponde cada contador. Aunque "sabemos" que el primer elemento de este array corresponde a la temperatura más baja, y el último a la temperatura más alta, no quedan aquí registradas cuáles son esas temperaturas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, muy interesante

Answer (score 0):

Una solución con Python puro:

```
with open("datos005.csv", "r") as datos:
    dicc = {}
    for temp in datos:
        llave = int(temp.strip())
        dicc[llave] = dicc.get(llave, 0) + 1
```

`dicc` es un diccionario indexado por temperatura y cuyo valor es la cantidad de veces que se repitió la misma.

Dado que el archivo contiene sólo una temperatura por línea, no necesito la libraría `csv` para procesarlo; basta con leer y convertir cada linea.

El método `get(llave, default)` te permite recuperar el valor de un diccionario. Si la entrada no existe, la función la genera automáticamente y le asigna el valor `default`. Así evitamos tener que usar un condicional para inicializar cada nueva temperatura.

#### Demo

```
with open("datos005.csv", "r") as datos:
    dicc = {}
    for temp in datos:
        llave = int(temp.strip())
        dicc[llave] = dicc.get(llave, 0) + 1

for temp in sorted(dicc.keys()):
    print(f"Temp {temp} ocurre {dicc[temp]}")
```

produce:

```
Temp -20 ocurre 18
Temp -19 ocurre 7
Temp -18 ocurre 20
Temp -17 ocurre 14
Temp -16 ocurre 15
Temp -15 ocurre 13
Temp -14 ocurre 15
Temp -13 ocurre 12
Temp -12 ocurre 4
Temp -11 ocurre 19
Temp -10 ocurre 18
Temp -9 ocurre 7
Temp -8 ocurre 15
Temp -7 ocurre 12
Temp -6 ocurre 15
Temp -5 ocurre 8
Temp -4 ocurre 5
Temp -3 ocurre 10
Temp -2 ocurre 9
Temp -1 ocurre 15
Temp 0 ocurre 16
Temp 1 ocurre 14
Temp 2 ocurre 10
Temp 3 ocurre 16
Temp 4 ocurre 14
Temp 5 ocurre 8
Temp 6 ocurre 11
Temp 7 ocurre 14
Temp 8 ocurre 11
Temp 9 ocurre 16
Temp 10 ocurre 12
Temp 11 ocurre 14
Temp 12 ocurre 17
Temp 13 ocurre 15
Temp 14 ocurre 16
Temp 15 ocurre 16
Temp 16 ocurre 18
Temp 17 ocurre 15
Temp 18 ocurre 6
Temp 19 ocurre 6
Temp 20 ocurre 11
Temp 21 ocurre 7
Temp 22 ocurre 14
Temp 23 ocurre 14
Temp 24 ocurre 14
Temp 25 ocurre 10
Temp 26 ocurre 15
Temp 27 ocurre 13
Temp 28 ocurre 22
Temp 29 ocurre 20
Temp 30 ocurre 14
Temp 31 ocurre 6
Temp 32 ocurre 9
Temp 33 ocurre 9
Temp 34 ocurre 11
Temp 35 ocurre 10
Temp 36 ocurre 17
Temp 37 ocurre 12
Temp 38 ocurre 13
Temp 39 ocurre 6
Temp 40 ocurre 6
Temp 41 ocurre 15
Temp 42 ocurre 10
Temp 43 ocurre 10
Temp 44 ocurre 6
Temp 45 ocurre 11
Temp 46 ocurre 12
Temp 47 ocurre 9
Temp 48 ocurre 10
Temp 49 ocurre 12
Temp 50 ocurre 9
Temp 51 ocurre 8
Temp 52 ocurre 14
Temp 53 ocurre 16
Temp 54 ocurre 10
Temp 55 ocurre 16
Temp 56 ocurre 11
Temp 57 ocurre 15
Temp 58 ocurre 12
Temp 59 ocurre 13
Temp 60 ocurre 12
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta :)